# ASP.NET gridview edit item template make searchable dropdown

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

i would like to know if there's any way to make a searchable dropdownlist (or with autocomplete) when the dropdownlist is generated inside a gridview during edit item template.

I cannot use the usual jQuery methods for dropdown automcomplete, as when the page is loaded, the id of the dropdownlist is not present yet, as the dropdownlist is generated only when the user edits the gridview.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can bind onLoad Event for the drop down

```
<asp:DropDownList onLoad="ddl_Load" ...>
```

then  at the code behind you can register your script

```
 protected void ddl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "msg", "addSearch('" + ((DropDownList)sender).ClientID + "');", true);
    }
```

the addSearch is a javascript function which contains the logic af adding the js plugin

Comment: Many thanks, i'll try your solution.. can you even by any chance recommend a good jquery search plugin?

Comment: usually, i use jquery ui auto complete